# WebView throws Receiver not registered: android.widget.ZoomButtonsController

Tags: android, webview

I see this exception sporadically raising up in my application (in the wild).
The WebView is used to display a jpg (using the zoom/scroll-capabilities of the Android version/the device instead reinventing the wheel and do all the reflection stuff).

I have no idea why this exception eventually could come up. Basically I can only think of an Android bug.

What I do (everything in GUI thread):

- display a thumbnail as preview first
- set getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false)
- when the regular picture is loaded, display that one instead
- set getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true)

Why setting ZoomControls on/off: The thumb should not be zoomable, as the WebView resets this on loadData as soon as the regular picture is available and displayed. Would be some bad user experience.

Example device this is happening:
HTC Desire@htc_wwe/htc_bravo/bravo/bravo:2.2/FRF91/226611:user/release-keys

I have exactly the same device/software and it never happend to me...

Any ideas?

Regards,
Oliver

Comment: nope... totally no idea why it happens - and it happens quite a lot.

Comment: I started a bounty on my question, hopefully someone will know something.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267639/how-to-safely-turn-webview-zooming-on-and-off-as-needed

Comment: the bounty didn't turn up any answers, but after digging around in the source code I found a workaround. You can see it in the answer to the question linked above.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will add this to the next version and check the incoming logs if the error still shows up. So many things to workaround these days (also for the ViewFlipper issue, which is an issue for me, too...)

Comment: As littleFluffyKitty pointed out in his question, the solution is to create your own webview class and add in onDestroy() method: webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

Comment: can you please, move your solution to answer, instead of comment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't like to answer myself, but littleFluffyKitty did not (only in comment).

Solution is in [How to safely turn WebView zooming on and off as needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267639/how-to-safely-turn-webview-zooming-on-and-off-as-needed)

a) create your own WebView class

```
public class MyWebView extends WebView {
```

b) add in it's onDestroy() method:

```
getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

That's it. Thanks to that, no more of those Exceptions show up.