# Existent app blowing up with android 3.0 XOOM. ZoomButtonsController Leak?

Tags: android, android-emulator, webview, zooming, android-webview

Unfortunately I don't have a XOOM device and the 3.0 emulator is **IMPOSSIBLE** to run even on the latest 2011 macbook pro.

I have asked one of the users to send me the error logs and the weirdest things are coming back. Many error logs!

Right now I "solved" the issue by disabling this line if SDK level is 11: webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

It looked like by adding the following line it would have work but I couldn't test since I don't have the device:
webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(true);

I've left only this line: webSettings.setSupportZoom(true) that doesn't affect the device.

The errors happen when you quit the activity that has the WebView with setDisplayZoomControls(true).

Please, advise, I have many user complaints. Any work-around is welcome too.

**Here are the stack traces:**

```
03-10 19:42:04.400 D/dalvikvm( 9132): GC_CONCURRENT freed 682K, 35% free 8749K/13383K, paused 7ms+3ms
03-10 19:42:08.630 D/BatteryService(  126): level:46 scale:100 status:4 health:2 present:true voltage: 7564 temperature: 271 technology: Li-ion AC powered:false USB powered:false icon:17302683 invalid charger:0
03-10 19:42:08.630 D/WifiService(  126): ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED pluggedType: 0
03-10 19:42:14.370 D/dalvikvm( 2122): GC_EXPLICIT freed 2K, 5% free 6209K/6531K, paused 5ms+1ms
03-10 19:42:29.950 D/SurfaceFlinger(  126): screenshot: sw=216, sh=135, minZ=0, maxZ=21025
03-10 19:42:29.960 D/SurfaceFlinger(  126): screenshot: result = OK
03-10 19:42:29.990 D/craigsnotifica( 9132): reseting info ttl
03-10 19:42:30.280 D/craigsnotifica( 9132): closing details
03-10 19:42:30.290 D/webviewglue( 9132): nativeDestroy view: 0x3c8188
03-10 19:42:30.300 W/WindowManager(  126): Force-removing child win Window{40f20a38 Panel:com.mufumbo.craigslist.

notification.android/com.mufumbo.craigslist.notification.android.AnnounceDetails paused=false} from container Window{41544810 com.mufumbo.craigslist.notification.android/com.mufumbo.craigslist.notification.android.AnnounceDetails paused=false}
03-10 19:42:30.310 E/WindowManager( 9132): Activity com.mufumbo.craigslist.notification.android.AnnounceDetails has leaked window android.widget.ZoomButtonsController$Container@40960188 that was originally added here
03-10 19:42:30.310 E/WindowManager( 9132): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.mufumbo.craigslist.notification.android.AnnounceDetails **has leaked window android.widget.ZoomButtonsController$Container@40960188 that was originally added here**
03-10 19:42:30.310 E/WindowManager( 9132): at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:276)
03-10 19:42:30.310 E/WindowManager( 9132): at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:152)
03-10 19:42:30.310 E/WindowManager( 9132): at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:95)
03-10 19:42:30.310 E/WindowManager( 9132): at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:514)
03-10 19:42:30.310 E/WindowManager( 9132): at android.widget.ZoomButtonsController.setVisible(ZoomButtonsController.java:371)
03-10 19:42:30.310 E/WindowManager( 9132): at android.webkit.ZoomControlEmbedded.show(ZoomControlEmbedded.java:41)
03-10 19:42:30.310 E/WindowManager( 9132): at android.webkit.ZoomManager.invokeZoomPicker(ZoomManager.java:999)
03-10 19:42:30.310 E/WindowManager( 9132): at android.webkit.WebView.startDrag(WebView.java:5990)
03-10 19:42:30.310 E/WindowManager( 9132): at android.webkit.WebView.handleTouchEventCommon(WebView.java:5626)
03-10 19:42:30.310 E/WindowManager( 9132): at android.webkit.WebView.onTouchEvent(WebView.java:5374)
03-10 19:42:30.310 E/WindowManager( 9132): at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:4600)
03-10 19:42:30.310 E/WindowManager( 9132): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1488)
03-10 19:42:30.310 E/WindowManager( 9132): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1256)
03-10 19:42:30.310 E/WindowManager( 9132): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1494)
03-10 19:42:30.310 E/WindowManager( 9132): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1269)
03-10 19:42:30.310 E/WindowManager( 9132): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1494)
03-10 19:42:30.310 E/WindowManager( 9132): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1269)
03-10 19:42:30.310 E/WindowManager( 9132): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1494)
03-10 19:42:30.310 E/WindowManager( 9132): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1269)
03-10 19:42:30.310 E/WindowManager( 9132): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1494)
03-10 19:42:30.310 E/WindowManager( 9132): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1269)
03-10 19:42:30.310 E/WindowManager( 9132): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1494)
03-10 19:42:30.310 E/WindowManager( 9132): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1269)
03-10 19:42:30.310 E/WindowManager( 9132): at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1700)
03-10 19:42:30.310 E/WindowManager( 9132): at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1270)
03-10 19:42:30.310 E/WindowManager( 9132): at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2271)
03-10 19:42:30.310 E/WindowManager( 9132): at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1680)
03-10 19:42:30.310 E/WindowManager( 9132): at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRoot.java:2272)
03-10 19:42:30.310 E/WindowManager( 9132): at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1958)
03-10 19:42:30.310 E/WindowManager( 9132): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-10 19:42:30.310 E/WindowManager( 9132): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
03-10 19:42:30.310 E/WindowManager( 9132): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997)
03-10 19:42:30.310 E/WindowManager( 9132): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-10 19:42:30.310 E/WindowManager( 9132): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
03-10 19:42:30.310 E/WindowManager( 9132): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
03-10 19:42:30.310 E/WindowManager( 9132): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
03-10 19:42:30.310 E/WindowManager( 9132): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-10 19:42:30.310 E/InputQueue-JNI( 9132): channel '40f20a38 Panel:com.mufumbo.craigslist.notification.android/com.mufumbo.craigslist.notification.android.AnnounceDetails (client)' ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
03-10 19:42:30.310 W/WindowManager(  126): Failed looking up window
03-10 19:42:30.310 W/WindowManager(  126): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window android.os.BinderProxy@41c303d8 does not exist
03-10 19:42:30.310 W/WindowManager(  126): at com.android.server.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:9415)
03-10 19:42:30.310 W/WindowManager(  126): at com.android.server.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:9406)
03-10 19:42:30.310 W/WindowManager(  126): at com.android.server.WindowManagerService.relayoutWindow(WindowManagerService.java:2777)
03-10 19:42:30.310 W/WindowManager(  126): at com.android.server.WindowManagerService$Session.relayout(WindowManagerService.java:6604)
03-10 19:42:30.310 W/WindowManager(  126): at android.view.IWindowSession$Stub.onTransact(IWindowSession.java:154)
03-10 19:42:30.310 W/WindowManager(  126): at com.android.server.WindowManagerService$Session.onTransact(WindowManagerService.java:6558)
03-10 19:42:30.310 W/WindowManager(  126): at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:320)
03-10 19:42:30.310 W/WindowManager(  126): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
03-10 19:42:30.320 W/WindowManager(  126): Failed looking up window
03-10 19:42:30.320 W/WindowManager(  126): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window android.os.BinderProxy@41c303d8 does not exist
03-10 19:42:30.320 W/WindowManager(  126): at com.android.server.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:9415)
03-10 19:42:30.320 W/WindowManager(  126): at com.android.server.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:9406)
03-10 19:42:30.320 W/WindowManager(  126): at com.android.server.WindowManagerService.removeWindow(WindowManagerService.java:2457)
03-10 19:42:30.320 W/WindowManager(  126): at com.android.server.WindowManagerService$Session.remove(WindowManagerService.java:6596)
03-10 19:42:30.320 W/WindowManager(  126): at android.view.IWindowSession$Stub.onTransact(IWindowSession.java:120)
03-10 19:42:30.320 W/WindowManager(  126): at com.android.server.WindowManagerService$Session.onTransact(WindowManagerService.java:6558)
03-10 19:42:30.320 W/WindowManager(  126): at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:320)
03-10 19:42:30.320 W/WindowManager(  126): at com.android.server.SystemServer.init1(Native Method)
03-10 19:42:30.320 W/WindowManager(  126): at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:640)
03-10 19:42:30.320 W/WindowManager(  126): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-10 19:42:30.320 W/WindowManager(  126): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
03-10 19:42:30.320 W/WindowManager(  126): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
03-10 19:42:30.320 W/WindowManager(  126): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
03-10 19:42:30.320 W/WindowManager(  126): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-10 19:42:30.330 E/ActivityThread( 9132): Activity com.mufumbo.craigslist.notification.android.AnnounceDetails has leaked IntentReceiver android.widget.ZoomButtonsController$1@40a2db40 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
03-10 19:42:30.330 E/ActivityThread( 9132): android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.mufumbo.craigslist.notification.android.AnnounceDetails has leaked IntentReceiver android.widget.ZoomButtonsController$1@40a2db40 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
03-10 19:42:30.330 E/ActivityThread( 9132): at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:751)
03-10 19:42:30.330 E/ActivityThread( 9132): at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:558)
03-10 19:42:30.330 E/ActivityThread( 9132): at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:991)
03-10 19:42:30.330 E/ActivityThread( 9132): at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:978)
03-10 19:42:30.330 E/ActivityThread( 9132): at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:972)
03-10 19:42:30.330 E/ActivityThread( 9132): at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:341)
03-10 19:42:30.330 E/ActivityThread( 9132): at
```

.................

```
03-10 19:42:30.340 W/ActivityManager(  126): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@40c0d278
03-10 19:42:30.400 D/AndroidRuntime( 9132): Shutting down VM
03-10 19:42:30.400 W/dalvikvm( 9132): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40175760)
03-10 19:42:30.400 D/SurfaceFlinger(  126): screenshot: sw=216, sh=135, minZ=0, maxZ=21015
03-10 19:42:30.400 E/AndroidRuntime( 9132): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-10 19:42:30.400 E/AndroidRuntime( 9132): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: android.widget.ZoomButtonsController$1@40a2db40
03-10 19:42:30.400 E/AndroidRuntime( 9132): at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:619)
03-10 19:42:30.400 E/AndroidRuntime( 9132): at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1014)
```

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267639/how-to-safely-turn-webview-zooming-on-and-off-as-needed/6880977#6880977)

Comment: I believe this is fixed in the last versions of the SDK, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, this window leaked error appears when your app crash.

But the actual error that caused it to crash happen Before this error is thrown. Do you have some other errors appearing somewhere before?

Comment: The crash happens and THEN the force-close window appear. I believe they fixed this in 3.2