# App Crashes after a long time of inactivity

Tags: android, crash

I get the following error when the app is not in use for longer than 15-30 mins. I am really new into this and app is currently published but I don't know how to fix this error. I see it's because of the ZoomButtonsController. Please see the following what I am doing in my code.

Code

```
webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        webview.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    }
```

Error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: android.widget.ZoomButtonsController$1@40813248
    at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:610)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver(ContextImpl.java:878)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:331) 
    at android.widget.ZoomButtonsController.setVisible(ZoomButtonsController.java:404)
    at android.widget.ZoomButtonsController$2.handleMessage(ZoomButtonsController.java:178)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: go here http://stackoverflow.com/a/8276511/2636887

Comment: you have to check this link it's helpful
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267639/how-to-safely-turn-webview-zooming-on-and-off-as-needed

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. That's the solution.